# Trouble with interfaces and parameters of objects

Tags: java, interface, constructor, parameter-passing, instance-variables

This is a difficult problem to describe so I will do my best.

Basically my program has two concrete classes: MovablePoint and MovableCircle. Both implement the interface Movable which has four methods: moveUp Down left right.

Now where I am stuck is that when I am constructing my MovableCircle I need to use an instance variable of MovablePoint to represent the center of the circle. However I also need the constructor of MovableCircle to take in 5 params: int x, int y, int xSpeed, int ySpeed, int radius. The first 4 params are the "center" of the circle and they should be instantiated by the MovablePoint.

Here is what I have:

```
public class MovableCircle implements Movable {
private int radius;
private int y;
private int x;
private int xSpeed;
private int ySpeed;
public MovablePoint circleCenter;

public MovableCircle (int x, int y, int xSpeed, int ySpeed, int radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
    this.x = circleCenter.getX();
    this.y = circleCenter.getY();
    this.xSpeed = circleCenter.getxSpeed();
    this.ySpeed = circleCenter.getySpeed();
}
```

Here also is the MovablePoint code if that helps:

```
public class MovablePoint implements Movable{
private int x;
private int y;
private int xSpeed;
private int ySpeed;

public MovablePoint(int x, int y, int xSpeed, 
        int ySpeed) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.xSpeed = xSpeed;
    this.ySpeed = ySpeed;
}
```

Obviously there is more code beyond what I have posted but I am fairly positive I have coded the class methods properly.. I believe my problem lies in the fact that I need to instantiate the MovableCircle's center with a MovablePoint but I'm not sure how to remedy it. Thanks for your help and I apologize if this problem is easily solved and I am just oblivious..

Comment: It seems you can reduce the instance variables for `MovableCircle` to just `int radius; MovablePoint circleCenter;`. No need to duplicate the fields the point already has. You can call `new MovablePoint(x,y,xs,ys);` from the circle's constructor.

Comment: Ah yes I see now, I think I was just misunderstanding the directions I was given. Thank you @Thilo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like:

```
public class MovableCircle implements Movable {
    private int radius;
    private MovablePoint circleCenter;

    public MovableCircle (int x, int y, int xSpeed, int ySpeed, int radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
        this.circleCenter = new MovablePoint(x, y, xSpeed, ySpeed);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @jas ! this definitely helped